# Closed-form for Floor Sum 2

Tags: summation, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Does a closed form exist for the following sum?

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor\lfloor\sqrt{k+P}\rfloor$

where $P$ is a positive odd integer.
Would a closed-form be possible if the factorization of $P$ is known?

Comment: You have $n$ and $N$ here - are they meant to be the same or different values?

Comment: They are different, $N$ in this case is a positive odd integer.

Comment: I would suggest not using such similar variable names in general; confusion is almost inevitable. In any case, a closed form seems highly unlikely particularly given the 'freeform' nature of $N$ - transitions in the sum can happen at essentially any point and tracking them looks highly difficult.

Comment: The problem is, however, interesting for $N=n$.

Comment: Good advice, I will update the variable names

Comment: Have you tried calculating it for, say, $P=5$ and $n=0,1,2,3,\dots,$ to see whether some p[attern emerges?

Comment: Yes, I can definitely see a pattern emerge, it looks something like this.

Comment: Let $t$ be the value for $\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor$ and let $s$ be the value for $\lfloor\sqrt{k+P}\rfloor$. For $P=5$, from $k=9$, you have $t=s$ 2 times, then $t+1=s$ P times, then $t=s$ 4 times, then $t+1=s$ P times, then $t=s$ 6 times and so on. But I cant figure it out for smaller $k$